# Service Mark (&#8480;) in <title> not displaying in IE8

Tags: titlebar

My client has requirement that Service Mark(SM) like TM should be displayed on the title bar of the browser.
I have got these html code for SM: 
And then i tried like this:

```
<title>Online Banking&#8480; - Service Agreement.</title>
```

This looks like

Online Banking℠ - Service Agreement.

This works fine in IE9 and Mozilla also but its displaying empty box in IE8 and IE7 also.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a problem in android browsers as well.

Just wrap in a span:

```
<span class"service-mark">sm</span>
```

And add some CSS to fake the superscript effect:

```
span.service-mark{
   vertical-align: super; 
   font-size: smaller; 
   line-height: 0;
}
```

Reference: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18919